# How to make label & other controls transparent with background image on windows mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, transparency, background-image

I am developing the smart device application in C#. I am new to the windows mobile. I have added the background image to the form in my application by using the following code. I want to make label & other controls on this form transparent so that my windows form will be displayed properly.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
                {
                    base.OnPaint(e);
                    Bitmap CreateCustomerImage = new Bitmap(@"/Storage Card/background.png");
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(CreateCustomerImage, 0, 0);
                }
```

how to do this ?  How to solve this problem? Can you provide me any code or link through which I can solve the above issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793261/how-to-make-the-background-image-transparent-in-windows-mobile/3793670#3793670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows CE doesn't inherently support transparent controls, which tends to be a huge pain.  You have to use something like ColorKey transparency, so in your OnPaint, you need to fill the background with a color (magenta is a popular one) and use SetColorKey to make that color transparent.

There are several tutorials online for colorkey transparency.  [Here is one](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/tamirk/archive/2008/11/21/creating-transparent-buttons-panels-and-other-control-with-compact-framework-and-putting-one-into-other.aspx) that I just found with a search engine that looks reasonable but feel free to search for others as well.

The place this falls down is when you have controls in a container control, which is then on the Form.  To get that to work right you have to cascade calls to clipping regions from the Form all the way down.  I don't have a ready sample of this that isn't inside a shipping project, so I can't easily post it.  If you run into this, though, update the question and I'll see if I can extract something.